# Error installing docker

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

Installed the docker according to the instruction:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ee/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository

And i have error:

```
E: Unable to locate package docker-ee
```

When updating the index of packages return error:

```
W: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'stable-17.03/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

What is this error?

p.s

```
lsb_release
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

uname -a
Linux dev-Cherepanov 4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 15:32:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You're installing the Enterprise edition. Why don't you contact Docker for support? Alternative try this instead: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

**There are some extra packages for ubuntu 14.04 linux-image-extra-* packages, which allow Docker EE to use the aufs storage driver and here the commands for them:**

```
 $ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install \
    linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) \
    linux-image-extra-virtual
```

and then set up the repository:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    software-properties-common
 $ curl -fsSL <DOCKER-EE-URL>/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
$ apt-key fingerprint 6D085F96

pub   4096R/6D085F96 2017-02-22
    Key fingerprint = DD91 1E99 5A64 A202 E859  07D6 BC14 F10B 6D08 5F96
uid       [ultimate] Docker Release (EE deb) <docker@docker.com>
sub   4096R/91A29FA3 2017-02-22
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] <DOCKER-EE-URL>/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable-17.03"
```

The last installation step of docker-ee:-

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install docker-ee
```

**Hope this works for you.**

Comment: I installed earlier these packages

Comment: try completely removing the docker and installing it again that's the option left with you because there was a problem when i was installing it but i followed the above thing and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to run

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
    "deb [arch=amd64] <DOCKER-EE-URL>/ubuntu \
    $(lsb_release -cs) \
    stable"
```

not

```
$sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] <DOCKER-EE-URL>/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable-17.03"
```

and then

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install docker-ee
```